# Using AQGridView for different sub-layouts of screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, aqgridview

I am looking to use AQGridView to layout a screen that has 3 different sub-layouts.
The top part of the screen should be laid out in a 2x5 grid, with each cell being occupied by a different graphic. This I have successfully accomplished.
The middle portion of the screen should be a single image that occupies the entire width of the screen, spanning across columns and of height 2 cells.

The bottom portion of the screen should be another grid layout with dimensions that may vary, but should fill up the remaining space. 
My question is, what's the best way to achieve this? Should I use 3 separate AQGridViews, one for each section, since the grid layouts are different, or can I fit the layout all in the same AQGridView? 
I have tried the latter approach, but I am having great difficulty in getting the image in the middle portion of the screen to properly span across cells. It is skewed to one side.

Comment: Why even use a relatively heavy framework at all, instead of just adding a few UIViews in the appropriate places? Either I am missing something, or you are trying to crack a nut with a sledgehammer here.

Comment: I agree here. I have used AQGridView a few times now and it's fantastic - but for a layout with as few elements as you have I'd just do it by hand. And you'd have to try quite hard to convince AQGridView to do cells of different sizes I think, probably using some tricky overdraw.